# How do I change X-Y positions of an circle on a canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying out canvas for the first time. After creating a circle I want to be able to change the position of the center of this circle at the click of a button. But I am unable to figure how to do so. Can someone suggest a method for it?

```css
#button{
height: 25px;
width:125px;
border: 1px solid black;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <div id="button" onclick="changePosition()">Click here</div>
    <canvas id="testCanvas" width="500px" height="500px"></canvas>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
 var a = canvas.getContext("2d");
        a.fillStyle = "#b22222";
 a.beginPath();
 a.arc(100,100,25,0,2*Math.PI);
 a.fill();
 
  function changePosition(){
    //what do I put here??
    
  }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32784387/javascript-canvas-not-redrawing
It is important to realize that you are just drawing to a bitmap. It is literally just an image file. You cannot just drag something around on it. There is no concept of an object. Only pixels. The programmer is responsible for maintaining the concept of the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redraw the scene. Create a function that resets the canvas and then draws the circle

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var circlePos = {
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
}

function renderCircle( circlePos ) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#b22222";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(circlePos.left, circlePos.top, 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
}

function changePosition() {
  circlePos.left += 10;
  if ( circlePos.left > canvas.width ) {
    circlePos.left = 0;
  }
  renderCircle( circlePos );
}
changePosition();
```

```css
#button {
  height: 25px;
  width: 125px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changePosition()">Click here</button>
<canvas id="testCanvas" width="500" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the help! I also want to ask, is this the only possible way to do it?

Comment: Yes, as you can see in this example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations :)

Comment: I updated my answer, since using `clearRect` is better to actually clear the canvas.